# My PHP code runs for the next html page rendered,not for the current one

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to make a project for school so I decided to make a quiz-game web-page.

Every question has 4 answers.

Every question,its' 4 answers and its' correct answer is taken randomly from a database.

The thing is I cant figure out how to fix this bug:
For example,the first question shown has B ) the correct answer.
The second question has C) the correct answer.

If I choose B as my answer,at question one,it will not show 'Correct answer',as expected,but 'Incorrect answer'.

If I choose C as my answer,at the first question,it will not show 'Incorrect answer',as expected,but 'Correct answer'.

This is my code:`

```
        $connection=mysql_connect('localhost','root',"");
        if(!$connection)
        {
            die("error".mysql_error());
        }

        $db_select=mysql_select_db("joculmintii",$connection);

        if(!$db_select)
        {
            die("error".mysql_error());
        }

            echo "<form id='formintrebare' method='post'>";

            $sub_result=mysql_query("SELECT * from intrebari ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1",$connection);

            if(!$sub_result)
            {
                die("database query failed". mysql_error());
            }

            while ($sub_row=mysql_fetch_array($sub_result))
            {

                $question=$sub_row["intrebare"];
                $option1=$sub_row["raspuns1"];
                $option2=$sub_row["raspuns2"];
                $option3=$sub_row["raspuns3"];
                $option4=$sub_row["raspuns4"];
                $answer=$sub_row["raspunscorect"];

                echo "<div id='intrebari'>
                    `<h3>Q:".$question."</h3>";   
                echo"
                    <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns1\" value=\"{$option1}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                    <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns2\" value=\"{$option2}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                    </br>
                    <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns3\" value=\"{$option3}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                    <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns4\" value=\"{$option4}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                    </br>
                    </br>

                    </div>";


                echo"</form>";

            }

                if(isset($_POST['raspuns1']))   
                {

                        if($answer==="raspuns1")
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }   
                } 

                elseif(isset($_POST['raspuns2']))   
                {
                        if($answer==="raspuns2")
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';

                            echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';

                            echo '</script>';
                        }   
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }   
                } 

                elseif (isset($_POST["raspuns3"]))   
                {
                        if($answer==="raspuns3")
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }   
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }   
                }

                elseif (isset($_POST['raspuns4'])) 
                {
                        if($answer==="raspuns4")
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }   
                }




     ?>`
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS: English is not my native language,so sorry for that.

Comment: Please note that you should not use mysql_* functions anymore to communicate with a database. If you have a decent teacher , he will point that out too as soon as you show him your work). mysql_* functions are considered unsafe and are deprecated since php 5.5 . Move over to PDO or mysqli.

For more information I suggest the following link, the author has summed up some great information in my opinion. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: I'd say that for teaching purposes, the deprecated `mysql` library isn't too bad at all. It's not for long-term production use, and the lack of parameterisation gives teachers an opportunity to show how SQL injection works, and how to defend against it with escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check your answer with the wrong question.

Everytime you do POST and update your page you send your current answer as a POST variable `$_POST['raspunsN']`. Then you Randomly get a new question from your database and then check the answer to the old question with the answer to the new question.

You have to store your old answer somehow and check against that. An easy way of doing this is using PHP Sessions.

Here's an example of how that might look

```
            session_start();
            if(isset($_POST['raspuns1']))   
            {
                $answer = $_SESSION['answer'];
                    if($answer==="raspuns1")
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }   
            } 

            elseif(isset($_POST['raspuns2']))   
            {
                    if($answer==="raspuns2")
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';

                        echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';

                        echo '</script>';
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }   
            } 

            elseif (isset($_POST["raspuns3"]))   
            {
                    if($answer==="raspuns3")
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }   
            }

            elseif (isset($_POST['raspuns4'])) 
            {
                    if($answer==="raspuns4")
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }   
            }  

    $connection=mysql_connect('localhost','root',"");
    if(!$connection)
    {
        die("error".mysql_error());
    }

    $db_select=mysql_select_db("joculmintii",$connection);

    if(!$db_select)
    {
        die("error".mysql_error());
    }

        echo "<form id='formintrebare' method='post'>";

        $sub_result=mysql_query("SELECT * from intrebari ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1",$connection);

        if(!$sub_result)
        {
            die("database query failed". mysql_error());
        }

        while ($sub_row=mysql_fetch_array($sub_result))
        {

            $question=$sub_row["intrebare"];
            $option1=$sub_row["raspuns1"];
            $option2=$sub_row["raspuns2"];
            $option3=$sub_row["raspuns3"];
            $option4=$sub_row["raspuns4"];
            $_SESSION['answer'] = $sub_row["raspunscorect"];

            echo "<div id='intrebari'>
                `<h3>Q:".$question."</h3>";   
            echo"
                <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns1\" value=\"{$option1}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns2\" value=\"{$option2}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                </br>
                <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns3\" value=\"{$option3}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                <input type= submit  name=\"raspuns4\" value=\"{$option4}\" class=\"imgClass\">
                </br>
                </br>

                </div>";


            echo"</form>";

        }
```

Please consider making a function out of your duplicate code:

```
    if($answer==="raspuns1")
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
        echo '</script>';
    }
```

Good luck on your journey of learning coding and PHP!

Comment: You you use the $_SESSION['answer'] variable before you declare it. I just added '$_SESSION['answer'];' after 'session_start();' though and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @alexandruKis: don't forget to accept this answer, when you are able to!

Comment: Oh right! The first time it's not gonna be declared, nice!

Comment: I wasnt home,sorry. Thanks for the prompt answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please use something like this. It will work:

```
if(isset($_POST['raspuns1']))   
                {

                        if($_POST['raspuns1']==$answer)
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns corect");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Raspuns gresit");';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }   
                }
```